# Parent wildcard variable polymorphic set to any of its children type c#

Tags: c#

I would like set a variable to any of it children's type. Much better explained with code.

If I have:

```
public class B : A {
    public int bCounter;
}

public class C : A {
    public int cCounter;
}
```

I would like to do:

```
A myVarible;
if (someCondition) {
    A = new B();
    A.bCounter++;
}
if (someOtherCondition) {
    A = new C();
    A.cCounter++;
}
```

Kind of setting the parent as a wildcard variable, not to set every possible children type.
Is this kind of shortcut or similar possible?

Comment: Your example should probably be `myVarible = new B(); myVarible.bCounter++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the variable `myVariable` is of type `A`, it is not possible to address it using derived type members. (`A` does not know about `B` members.) Depending on your scenario, there are multiple options.

If there is no control over `A`, or the business logic requires it, you may be required to redeclare the variable to get it to compile.

```
if (someCondition) {
    var b = new B();
    b.bCounter++;
    myVariable = b;
}

if (someOtherCondition) {
    var c = new B();
    c.cCounter++;
    myVariable = c;
}
```

If it makes sense to do so, you could generate a method on `A` to `IncrementCounter()`:

```
abstract class A
{
   abstract void IncrementCounter();
}

public class B : A {
    public int bCounter;

    override void IncrementCounter() => bCounter++;

}

public class C : A {
    public int cCounter;

    override void IncrementCounter() => cCounter++;
}
```

This in turn lets you simplify your business logic:

```
A myVariable;
if (someCondition) {
    myVariable = new B();
}
if (someOtherCondition) {
    myVariable = new C();
}

myVariable.IncrementCounter();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the both declarations `var b = new B();` and `var c = new B();` is what I wanted to avoid, to have a one only declaration for any possible children type assignment. Seems that is not possible. Thanks